# Random "Could not find the included template" Errors in CF11

Tags: coldfusion

I am seeing random "Could not find the included template" exceptions on my ColdFusion website. They are always for one file, but that file does exist and is included hundreds of times throughout the website and I don't see errors 99% of the time. The error only occurs randomly (6 times in the past 4 weeks). I would like to know why this is happening and how I can prevent it.

Comment: Is the file with the `include` code the same for each error?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, every time. It's a CF template that displays the footer of the page.

Comment: How do you reference the file? Relative to the current path (e.g. `footer.cfm`), relative to the root path (e.g. `/footer.cfm`) or absolute (e.g. `/var/www/website/footer.cfm`)?

Comment: You need to turn on some more logging. I suspect there is a request that causes this and I bet the request is uncommon

Comment: @EricBelair, I don't think you understood my question.

Comment: @DanBracuk the file is referenced with a relative path "/of/inc/footer.cfm" where "/of/inc/" is a physical directory below the web root.

Answer (score -3):

You say the file is a footer and that it "is included hundreds of times throughout the website". Do you mean at hundreds of page locations? If so, then this suggests a possible design flaw.

You should strive to include the footer in one location only, the Application file. (Or failing that, in as few locations as possible). It is likely that the error is being caused by cfinclude code in a page that is accessed 1% of the time.

Comment: This is not an answer but an opinion/criticism - and a flawed one at that. The Application.cfc file is not meant for including content. I am trying to find out the reason why this issue is happening. A simple CFINCLUDE to an existing file should not throw an exception, regardless of how many times that include is used.

Comment: @Eric Belair, what I have given you is neither opinion nor criticism. It is best-practice, the DRY heuristic: Don't Repeat Yourself. This is relevant because you imply that you do the include in hundreds of pages. If so, then that is poor design. For example, it increases the chance that the cfinclude code is in a location which makes it to point to a non-existent relative path. Besides, you seem to misunderstand my suggestion regarding the Application file. Typically, footers are included in the onRequestEnd event of Application.cfc.

Comment: if you have a "suggestion", add a comment, don't enter it as a answer.

Comment: Can't a suggestion be an answer? In other words, may one not suggest an answer?